# Android Eclipse Break Point Problem

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

i am using eclipse 3.6 for my android app and I dont know how to debug and insert a break point in eclipse so can you please give me any link or guide me. I tried a lot to search on google but none of them were easy to understand.

i also tried this link:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecbug/
but that was also not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be difficult. You insert a breakpoint by right-clicking at the gray line at the left of your code and then selecting "Toggle breakpoint". A circle should appear.

In order for the breakpoint to be active, start your application in debug mode. You do that by clicking at the "bug" icon ("Debug as..").

Comment: try {
int logoTimer = 0;
while(logoTimer < 5000) {
sleep(100);
logoTimer = logoTimer + 100;  
}

Comment: i have the above code and inserted break point at logoTimer = logoTimer + 100; line then what should i do?

Comment: You need to start your application in debugging mode. You can do that by pressing the "Debug as" button (the icon is a bug). Do do and monitor the messages in the console. If it doesn't work, it could be that Eclipse can't attach the debugger to the emulator or your device. Post the messages in the console to get some help.